# select 2 multi select option how to pre populate options in a selected order

Tags: php, jquery

I am using referring this [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcrazyness/n4n5Y/) 
and  I am storing the selected value in a same order into database.

How I can fetch and show the items in same order. Now its showing based on the order which I have entered

```
<body>Multiple select example
    <div class="selectRow">
        <!-- Using data-placeholder below to set place holder value versus putting in configuration -->
        <select id="multipleSelectExample" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple>
            <option value="1" <?PHP if(in_array("1",$arrayval)){?> selected="selected" <?PHP } ?>>Option 1</option>
            <option value="2" <?PHP if(in_array("2",$arrayval)){?> selected="selected" <?PHP } ?>>Option 2</option>
            <option value="3" <?PHP if(in_array("3",$arrayval)){?> selected="selected" <?PHP } ?>>Option 3</option>
            <option value="4" <?PHP if(in_array("4",$arrayval)){?> selected="selected" <?PHP } ?>>Option 4</option>
            <option value="5" <?PHP if(in_array("5",$arrayval)){?> selected="selected" <?PHP } ?>>Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

script

```
 $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#multipleSelectExample").select2();

var vals = [];

  $('#multipleSelectExample').change(function(e) {
    for(var i=0; i <$('#selector option').length; i++) {
      if ($($('#selector option')[i]).prop('selected') ) {
        if (!vals.includes(i)) {
          vals.push(i);
        }
      } else {
        if (vals.includes(i)) { 
          vals.splice(vals.indexOf(i), 1);
        }
      }
    }

  })

  $("#button").click(function(e) {
    var order = '';
    vals.forEach(function(ele) 
    {
      if(order == '')   
       order = $($('#selector option')[ele]).val();
      else
       order +=  ',' + $($('#selector option')[ele]).val();
    })
    $("#seletedorder").val(order)

  })
        }
    );
```

In this I am selecting option4 and option3 and storing in a same order into database like option4,option3. But while fetching how can i maintain the same order

now its showing option3,option4

seletedorder is hidden type. I am storing the selected value in this and this selectedorder value i am storing into database. But while returning its not showing  in the same order

Thank you

Comment: from where you are fetching? I can't see any code regarding fetching or storing somewhere!

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo i have updated my code

Comment: so you are storing in database with correct order.! and the fetched value from database shows in wrong order? if so then you are suppose to check on the **fetch query **.

Comment: fetch query is showing correctly. but the ordering shows wrong.